# socket programming

Tags: c#, sockets

I Have a Problem in Connect to to network with mobile windows ce socket programming c# (win ce )
after connect to tcp/ip port throw 10060 error

Comment: Show your client and server code and IP address

Answer (score 1):

As decribed on [this page from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668.aspx) it's a timeout error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: connection failed,is the server running?an error message is available for this exception..... netcfv35.message.e...

Comment: @user538946: In this case it seems like your CE application can not connect to your server. It's very difficult to know what fails; Are you sure they are reachable from eachother? Do you have an Internet connection on your CE device? Is the server reachable from any other computer or device? Is the server application running? Are you connecting to the correct port?